# On Firefox, CORS request gives error ":" (colon)

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, cors

On Chrome, I'm having no troubles making a cross domain request, however on Firefox (Ubuntu 14.04), I get an error that consists only of a colon on the line that calls for the xmlhttprequest.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/folder/file.xml", false);
```

The error message is just ":".

Comment: What, *exactly* is the error message?

Comment: ":". I have no idea why it just gives me that.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to detect errors?

Comment: It's the Firefox console.

Comment: In a similar situation I am getting the same issue with Firefox; debugging with Firebug and the built in tools. I changed my url from https://domain/professional/etc to https://domain/admin/etc and the error popped up. The error is simply a colon, the line of code is the one that opens the request. This does not occur in Chrome. I am currently using Firefox 32 Beta.

Comment: The error turned out to be related to loading http content on an https page.

Answer (score 8):

## Try Disabling AdBlock

I was having a similar issue where all of my XMLHttpRequests were going through except for a few very specific ones where even minor URL changes fixed the problem. And the only thing I was getting was a colon : in the console. In the end I realized that AdBlockPlus was blocking at least one these requests from going through (the request had 'Banners' in the URL).

So I'm not sure if this would have solved your problem, but I've encountered it multiple times.

Comment: Can confirm this was the exact issue I was having. Have been scratching my head for the last hour or so trying to work out WTF is going on. Disabled Adblock Edge and everything worked!

Comment: I was using Privacy Badger and it was causing this exact problem while attempting to access the identity server, and disabling it fixed this.  However it only appeared on attempts to access an HTTPS site.

Comment: I just spent an hour figuring out why my stuff suddenly doesn't work anymore. I had switched from a 10.0.0.x local network to 192.168.1.x and that's when AdBlockPlus started blocking things. Presumably it does so because some websites contain malware that tries to access your router at 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

using Firebug, the issue turned out to be

```
Blocked loading mixed active content
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on a CORS POST request.
I'm using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/  to bypass the Same-origin policy.
The problem was **NoScript blocking the external domain**, so in case you're using an external API in your request, this might solve it.

Comment: link-only answer is not good on SO. Please insert essential infos in your answer.

Comment: I clarified my answer, however that is all the essential info I have.

Comment: does this work for CORS blocked by AdBlock extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190324/5994041), however the problem for me isn't present neither with AdBlock nor with uBlock.

#### It's present with **[`uMatrix`](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix)**.

You can find that it blocks the request at this URL:

```
chrome://umatrix/content/logger-ui.html
```

You can enable it manually when clicking on that field:

[image]

and choosing to enable `XHR` in the uMatrix popup:

[image]

The blocking persists even if you have the code packaged in an Add-on that's correctly installed (the blue bar containts `Internal UUID` of a Firefox Add-on), therefore if you've ever wondered why some Add-ons don't work while uMatrix (or likes) is enabled, this might be one of the reasons.